# Raspberry Pi Zero W auto login

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, raspbian-buster, login, lightdm

I am trying to enable an auto login on a Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspbian Booster 10.

I am interested in the Desktop interface, not the Command one, which works with auto login enabled.

I have tried the following:

1. sudo raspi config
2. modifying the lightdm conf for autologin-user and timeout

If necessary, i will provide the lightdm logs (cannot pastebin here, for whatever reason).

These have not worked. The login prompt always appears.

**Update** with info from comment:
I connect with SSH to the RPi, but when it is deployed, it should start with the graphical interface, because it has to show videos on the screen (through HDMI, on a monitor). The login prompt is the default prompt shown when the RPi starts up.

Comment: pastebin.com/9rMtmgkm

Comment: If your setup is headless, then what login prompt you are talking about? SSH?

Comment: I connect with SSH to the RPi, but when it is deployed, it should start with the graphical interface, because it has to show videos on the screen (through HDMI, on a monitor). The login prompt is the default prompt shown when the RPi starts up.